# Sanger Sequencing Knitting Error

Tags: r, sequence-alignment, bioconductor

I am doing a project where I am reproducing the analysis from the article "sangeranalyseR: Simple and Interactive Processing of Sanger Sequencing Data in R". Below is the example chunk for Sanger Alignment. Below are the package and datasets.

```r
library(sangeranalyseR)
data("sangerAlignmentData")
data("sangerContigData")
data("sangerReadFData")
```

Below is the code for Sanger Alignment, similar to the code for Sanger Contig and Sanger Reading.

```r
rawDataDir <- system.file("extdata", package = "sangeranalyseR")
fastaFN <- file.path(rawDataDir, "fasta", "SangerAlignment", "Sanger_all_reads.fa")
my_sangerAlignmentFa <- new("SangerAlignment",
                            inputSource          = "FASTA",
                            processMethod        = "REGEX",
                            FASTA_File           = fastaFN,
                            REGEX_SuffixForward  = "_[0-9]*_F$",
                        REGEX_SuffixReverse  = "_[0-9]*_R$",
                            refAminoAcidSeq      = "SRQWLFSTNHKDIGTLYFIFGAWAGMVGTSLSILIRAELGHPGALIGDDQIYNVIVTAHAFIMIFFMVMPIMIGGFGNWLVPLMLGAPDMAFPRMNNMSFWLLPPALSLLLVSSMVENGAGTGWTVYPPLSAGIAHGGASVDLAIFSLHLAGISSILGAVNFITTVINMRSTGISLDRMPLFVWSVVITALLLLLSLPVLAGAITMLLTDRNLNTSFFDPAGGGDPILYQHLFWFFGHPEVYILILPGFGMISHIISQESGKKETFGSLGMIYAMLAIGLLGFIVWAHHMFTVGMDVDTRAYFTSATMIIAVPTGIKIFSWLATLHGTQLSYSPAILWALGFVFLFTVGGLTGVVLANSSVDIILHDTYYVVAHFHYVLSMGAVFAIMAGFIHWYPLFTGLTLNNKWLKSHFIIMFIGVNLTFFPQHFLGLAGMPRRYSDYPDAYTTWNIVSTIGSTISLLGILFFFFIIWESLVSQRQVIYPIQLNSSIEWYQNTPPAEHSYSELPLLTN",
                            minReadsNum           = 2,
                            minReadLength         = 20,
                            minFractionCall       = 0.5,
                            maxFractionLost       = 0.5,
                            geneticCode           = GENETIC_CODE,
                            acceptStopCodons      = TRUE,
                            readingFrame          = 1,
                            processorsNum         = 1)

launchApp(my_sangerAlignmentFa)

writeFasta(my_sangerAlignmentFa,
           outputDir         = tempdir(),
           compress          = FALSE,
           compression_level = NA,
           selection         = "all")

generateReport(my_sangerAlignmentFa,
               outputDir           = tempdir(),
               includeSangerRead   = TRUE,
               includeSangerContig = TRUE)
```

There are two problems that occurred for me. One is that the launchapp() function created an error for me stating

```
INFO [2023-03-01 14:25:52] Your input is 'SangerAlignment' S4 instance
INFO [2023-03-01 14:25:52] SangerAlignment with 'FASTA' inputSource
cannot run Shiny app (You don't need to do trimming or base calling)
NULL
```

How can I fix this error?

Another error that occurred within knitting. I ran the same code without the launchapp() function and an error that I never seen before said this

```
Quitting from lines NA-219 (SangerRead_Report_fasta.Rmd)  Error in parse_block(g[-1], g[1], params.src, markdown_mode) : 
Duplicate chunk label 'unnamed-chunk-1', which has been used for the chunk:
library(sangeranalyseR) library(rentrez) Calls: <Anonymous> ...
process_file -> split_file -> lapply -> FUN -> parse_block

Execution halted
```

Is it my RStudio or is the code itself. Is there anything I am missing?

````
sessionInfo(sangeranalysesR)
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
character(0)

other attached packages:
[1] sangeranalyseR_1.8.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] utils_4.2.2            nlme_3.1-161          
  [3] fs_1.6.1               bitops_1.0-7          
  [5] bit64_4.0.5            httr_1.4.4            
  [7] GenomeInfoDb_1.34.6    tools_4.2.2           
  [9] bslib_0.4.2            utf8_1.2.2            
 [11] R6_2.5.1               DT_0.27               
 [13] DBI_1.1.3              lazyeval_0.2.2        
 [15] BiocGenerics_0.44.0    colorspace_2.1-0      
 [17] rhdf5filters_1.10.0    ade4_1.7-20           
 [19] withr_2.5.0            tidyselect_1.2.0      
 [21] gridExtra_2.3          phangorn_2.11.1       
 [23] bit_4.0.5              compiler_4.2.2        
 [25] cli_3.5.0              datasets_4.2.2        
 [27] shinyjs_2.1.0          plotly_4.10.1         
 [29] ggdendro_0.1.23        base_4.2.2            
 [31] sass_0.4.5             scales_1.2.1          
 [33] quadprog_1.5-8         stringr_1.5.0         
 [35] digest_0.6.31          rmarkdown_2.20        
 [37] sangerseqR_1.34.0      XVector_0.38.0        
 [39] pkgconfig_2.0.3        htmltools_0.5.4       
 [41] sessioninfo_1.2.2      fastmap_1.1.0         
 [43] excelR_0.4.0           grDevices_4.2.2       
 [45] htmlwidgets_1.6.1      rlang_1.0.6           
 [47] rstudioapi_0.14        RSQLite_2.2.20        
 [49] shiny_1.7.4            jquerylib_0.1.4       
 [51] generics_0.1.3         jsonlite_1.8.4        
 [53] BiocParallel_1.32.5    zip_2.2.2             
 [55] dplyr_1.1.0            RCurl_1.98-1.10       
 [57] magrittr_2.0.3         GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9
 [59] biomformat_1.26.0      Matrix_1.5-3          
 [61] Rhdf5lib_1.20.0        Rcpp_1.0.10           
 [63] munsell_0.5.0          S4Vectors_0.36.1      
 [65] fansi_1.0.4            logger_0.2.2          
 [67] DECIPHER_2.26.0        ape_5.6-2             
 [69] shinycssloaders_1.0.0  lifecycle_1.0.3       
 [71] yaml_2.3.7             stringi_1.7.12        
 [73] MASS_7.3-58.2          zlibbioc_1.44.0       
 [75] rhdf5_2.42.0           plyr_1.8.8            
 [77] grid_4.2.2             blob_1.2.3            
 [79] parallel_4.2.2         promises_1.2.0.1      
 [81] shinydashboard_0.7.2   crayon_1.5.2          
 [83] methods_4.2.2          lattice_0.20-45       
 [85] Biostrings_2.66.0      zeallot_0.1.0         
 [87] knitr_1.42             pillar_1.8.1          
 [89] igraph_1.3.5           seqinr_4.2-23         
 [91] reshape2_1.4.4         codetools_0.2-19      
 [93] stats4_4.2.2           fastmatch_1.1-3       
 [95] reprex_2.0.2           BiocVersion_3.16.0    
 [97] glue_1.6.2             evaluate_0.20         
 [99] BiocManager_1.30.20    data.table_1.14.6     
[101] vctrs_0.5.2            httpuv_1.6.8          
[103] graphics_4.2.2         gtable_0.3.1          
[105] purrr_1.0.1            tidyr_1.3.0           
[107] cachem_1.0.6           ggplot2_3.4.0         
[109] openxlsx_4.2.5.1       xfun_0.36             
[111] mime_0.12              xtable_1.8-4          
[113] later_1.3.0            viridisLite_0.4.1     
[115] tibble_3.1.8           stats_4.2.2           
[117] memoise_2.0.1          IRanges_2.32.0        
[119] shinyWidgets_0.7.6     ellipsis_0.3.2        
[121] BiocStyle_2.26.0
```
````

Answer (score 3):

Your code runs without error on my laptop (macOS 13.2.1; R v4.2.2; Rstudio 2022.07.2), so I have some further questions that might help with troubleshooting (too many to include in a comment):

- Does the [example from the docs](https://github.com/roblanf/sangeranalyseR#quick-start-guide) run without errors/warnings on your system?
- Did you install the sangeranalyseR package via Bioconductor (per the [docs](https://github.com/roblanf/sangeranalyseR#quick-start-guide))?
- Do you have the most up-to-date Bioconducter installed?
- Have you tried running the example code in a 'fresh' session?
- Are you able to please run the command `sessionInfo()` and edit your question to include the output?
- If you run your example via the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/), are there any differences between your output and my output?

The code from your question run on my laptop:

```r
# BiocManager::install("sangeranalyseR")
library(sangeranalyseR)
#> Loading required package: stringr
#> Loading required package: ape
#> Loading required package: Biostrings
#> Loading required package: BiocGenerics
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'BiocGenerics'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     IQR, mad, sd, var, xtabs
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     anyDuplicated, aperm, append, as.data.frame, basename, cbind,
#>     colnames, dirname, do.call, duplicated, eval, evalq, Filter, Find,
#>     get, grep, grepl, intersect, is.unsorted, lapply, Map, mapply,
#>     match, mget, order, paste, pmax, pmax.int, pmin, pmin.int,
#>     Position, rank, rbind, Reduce, rownames, sapply, setdiff, sort,
#>     table, tapply, union, unique, unsplit, which.max, which.min
#> Loading required package: S4Vectors
#> Loading required package: stats4
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'S4Vectors'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     expand.grid, I, unname
#> Loading required package: IRanges
#> Loading required package: XVector
#> Loading required package: GenomeInfoDb
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Biostrings'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ape':
#> 
#>     complement
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     strsplit
#> Loading required package: DECIPHER
#> Loading required package: RSQLite
#> Loading required package: parallel
#> Loading required package: reshape2
#> Loading required package: phangorn
#> Loading required package: sangerseqR
#> Loading required package: gridExtra
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'gridExtra'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:BiocGenerics':
#> 
#>     combine
#> Loading required package: shiny
#> Loading required package: shinydashboard
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'shinydashboard'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     box
#> Loading required package: shinyjs
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'shinyjs'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     runExample
#> The following object is masked from 'package:RSQLite':
#> 
#>     show
#> The following object is masked from 'package:Biostrings':
#> 
#>     show
#> The following object is masked from 'package:GenomeInfoDb':
#> 
#>     show
#> The following object is masked from 'package:XVector':
#> 
#>     show
#> The following object is masked from 'package:IRanges':
#> 
#>     show
#> The following object is masked from 'package:S4Vectors':
#> 
#>     show
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats4':
#> 
#>     show
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:methods':
#> 
#>     removeClass, show
#> Loading required package: data.table
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'data.table'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:reshape2':
#> 
#>     dcast, melt
#> The following object is masked from 'package:IRanges':
#> 
#>     shift
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:S4Vectors':
#> 
#>     first, second
#> Loading required package: plotly
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'plotly'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     last_plot
#> The following object is masked from 'package:phangorn':
#> 
#>     add_boxplot
#> The following object is masked from 'package:XVector':
#> 
#>     slice
#> The following object is masked from 'package:IRanges':
#> 
#>     slice
#> The following object is masked from 'package:S4Vectors':
#> 
#>     rename
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     layout
#> Loading required package: DT
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'DT'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     dataTableOutput, renderDataTable
#> Loading required package: zeallot
#> Loading required package: excelR
#> Loading required package: shinycssloaders
#> Loading required package: ggdendro
#> Loading required package: shinyWidgets
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'shinyWidgets'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:shinyjs':
#> 
#>     alert
#> Loading required package: openxlsx
#> Loading required package: tools
#> Loading required package: rmarkdown
#> Loading required package: knitr
#> Loading required package: seqinr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'seqinr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     a
#> The following object is masked from 'package:sangerseqR':
#> 
#>     read.abif
#> The following object is masked from 'package:Biostrings':
#> 
#>     translate
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:ape':
#> 
#>     as.alignment, consensus
#> Loading required package: BiocStyle
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'BiocStyle'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:rmarkdown':
#> 
#>     html_document, md_document, pdf_document
#> The following object is masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     markdown
#> Loading required package: logger
#> Welcome to sangeranalyseR
data("sangerAlignmentData")
data("sangerContigData")
data("sangerReadFData")

rawDataDir <- system.file("extdata", package = "sangeranalyseR")
fastaFN <- file.path(rawDataDir, "fasta", "SangerAlignment", "Sanger_all_reads.fa")
my_sangerAlignmentFa <- new("SangerAlignment",
                            inputSource          = "FASTA",
                            processMethod        = "REGEX",
                            FASTA_File           = fastaFN,
                            REGEX_SuffixForward  = "_[0-9]*_F$",
                        REGEX_SuffixReverse  = "_[0-9]*_R$",
                            refAminoAcidSeq      = "SRQWLFSTNHKDIGTLYFIFGAWAGMVGTSLSILIRAELGHPGALIGDDQIYNVIVTAHAFIMIFFMVMPIMIGGFGNWLVPLMLGAPDMAFPRMNNMSFWLLPPALSLLLVSSMVENGAGTGWTVYPPLSAGIAHGGASVDLAIFSLHLAGISSILGAVNFITTVINMRSTGISLDRMPLFVWSVVITALLLLLSLPVLAGAITMLLTDRNLNTSFFDPAGGGDPILYQHLFWFFGHPEVYILILPGFGMISHIISQESGKKETFGSLGMIYAMLAIGLLGFIVWAHHMFTVGMDVDTRAYFTSATMIIAVPTGIKIFSWLATLHGTQLSYSPAILWALGFVFLFTVGGLTGVVLANSSVDIILHDTYYVVAHFHYVLSMGAVFAIMAGFIHWYPLFTGLTLNNKWLKSHFIIMFIGVNLTFFPQHFLGLAGMPRRYSDYPDAYTTWNIVSTIGSTISLLGILFFFFIIWESLVSQRQVIYPIQLNSSIEWYQNTPPAEHSYSELPLLTN",
                            minReadsNum           = 2,
                            minReadLength         = 20,
                            minFractionCall       = 0.5,
                            maxFractionLost       = 0.5,
                            geneticCode           = GENETIC_CODE,
                            acceptStopCodons      = TRUE,
                            readingFrame          = 1,
                            processorsNum         = 2)
#> Assessing frameshifts in nucleotide sequences:
#> ================================================================================
#> 
#> Time difference of 0.05 secs
#> Assessing frameshifts in nucleotide sequences:
#> ================================================================================
#> 
#> Time difference of 0.03 secs
#> Assessing frameshifts in nucleotide sequences:
#> ================================================================================
#> 
#> Time difference of 0.03 secs
#> Assessing frameshifts in nucleotide sequences:
#> ================================================================================
#> 
#> Time difference of 0.03 secs

writeFasta(my_sangerAlignmentFa,
           outputDir         = tempdir(),
           compress          = FALSE,
           compression_level = NA,
           selection         = "all")

generateReport(my_sangerAlignmentFa,
               outputDir           = tempdir(),
               includeSangerRead   = TRUE,
               includeSangerContig = TRUE)
#> processing file: SangerRead_Report_fasta.Rmd
#> output file: SangerRead_Report_fasta.knit.md
#> /usr/local/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS SangerRead_Report_fasta.knit.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output /private/var/folders/gf/3p_ynkts411bs238rtw3y0b40000gn/T/Rtmplj2Uy8/SangerAlignment/Achl_ACHLO006-09/Sanger_all_reads/SangerRead_Report_fasta.html --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --embed-resources --standalone --variable bs3=TRUE --section-divs --table-of-contents --toc-depth 3 --variable toc_float=1 --variable toc_selectors=h1,h2,h3 --variable toc_collapsed=1 --variable toc_smooth_scroll=1 --variable toc_print=1 --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable theme=bootstrap --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url=https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' --include-in-header /var/folders/gf/3p_ynkts411bs238rtw3y0b40000gn/T//Rtmplj2Uy8/rmarkdown-str3926187706b9.html
#> 
#> Output created: /private/var/folders/gf/3p_ynkts411bs238rtw3y0b40000gn/T/RtmplI8nQX/SangerAlignment/SangerAlignment_Report.html
#> [1] "/private/var/folders/gf/3p_ynkts411bs238rtw3y0b40000gn/T/RtmplI8nQX/SangerAlignment/SangerAlignment_Report.html"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Example from the docs:

```r
library(sangeranalyseR)
#> Loading required package: stringr
#> Loading required package: ape
#> Loading required package: Biostrings
#> Loading required package: BiocGenerics
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'BiocGenerics'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     IQR, mad, sd, var, xtabs
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     anyDuplicated, aperm, append, as.data.frame, basename, cbind,
#>     colnames, dirname, do.call, duplicated, eval, evalq, Filter, Find,
#>     get, grep, grepl, intersect, is.unsorted, lapply, Map, mapply,
#>     match, mget, order, paste, pmax, pmax.int, pmin, pmin.int,
#>     Position, rank, rbind, Reduce, rownames, sapply, setdiff, sort,
#>     table, tapply, union, unique, unsplit, which.max, which.min
#> Loading required package: S4Vectors
#> Loading required package: stats4
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'S4Vectors'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     expand.grid, I, unname
#> Loading required package: IRanges
#> Loading required package: XVector
#> Loading required package: GenomeInfoDb
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Biostrings'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ape':
#> 
#>     complement
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     strsplit
#> Loading required package: DECIPHER
#> Loading required package: RSQLite
#> Loading required package: parallel
#> Loading required package: reshape2
#> Loading required package: phangorn
#> Loading required package: sangerseqR
#> Loading required package: gridExtra
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'gridExtra'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:BiocGenerics':
#> 
#>     combine
#> Loading required package: shiny
#> Loading required package: shinydashboard
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'shinydashboard'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     box
#> Loading required package: shinyjs
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'shinyjs'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     runExample
#> The following object is masked from 'package:RSQLite':
#> 
#>     show
#> The following object is masked from 'package:Biostrings':
#> 
#>     show
#> The following object is masked from 'package:GenomeInfoDb':
#> 
#>     show
#> The following object is masked from 'package:XVector':
#> 
#>     show
#> The following object is masked from 'package:IRanges':
#> 
#>     show
#> The following object is masked from 'package:S4Vectors':
#> 
#>     show
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats4':
#> 
#>     show
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:methods':
#> 
#>     removeClass, show
#> Loading required package: data.table
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'data.table'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:reshape2':
#> 
#>     dcast, melt
#> The following object is masked from 'package:IRanges':
#> 
#>     shift
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:S4Vectors':
#> 
#>     first, second
#> Loading required package: plotly
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'plotly'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     last_plot
#> The following object is masked from 'package:phangorn':
#> 
#>     add_boxplot
#> The following object is masked from 'package:XVector':
#> 
#>     slice
#> The following object is masked from 'package:IRanges':
#> 
#>     slice
#> The following object is masked from 'package:S4Vectors':
#> 
#>     rename
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     layout
#> Loading required package: DT
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'DT'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     dataTableOutput, renderDataTable
#> Loading required package: zeallot
#> Loading required package: excelR
#> Loading required package: shinycssloaders
#> Loading required package: ggdendro
#> Loading required package: shinyWidgets
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'shinyWidgets'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:shinyjs':
#> 
#>     alert
#> Loading required package: openxlsx
#> Loading required package: tools
#> Loading required package: rmarkdown
#> Loading required package: knitr
#> Loading required package: seqinr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'seqinr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     a
#> The following object is masked from 'package:sangerseqR':
#> 
#>     read.abif
#> The following object is masked from 'package:Biostrings':
#> 
#>     translate
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:ape':
#> 
#>     as.alignment, consensus
#> Loading required package: BiocStyle
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'BiocStyle'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:rmarkdown':
#> 
#>     html_document, md_document, pdf_document
#> The following object is masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     markdown
#> Loading required package: logger
#> Welcome to sangeranalyseR
rawDataDir <- system.file("extdata", package = "sangeranalyseR")
parentDir <- file.path(rawDataDir, 'Allolobophora_chlorotica', 'ACHLO')

ACHLO_contigs <- SangerAlignment(ABIF_Directory     = parentDir,
                                 REGEX_SuffixForward = "_[0-9]*_F.ab1$",
                             REGEX_SuffixReverse = "_[0-9]*_R.ab1$")

launchApp(ACHLO_contigs)
writeFasta(ACHLO_contigs)
generateReport(ACHLO_contigs)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

My sessionInfo output:

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Big Sur ... 10.16
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/C/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#>  [1] tools     parallel  stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
#>  [8] datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] sangeranalyseR_1.8.0  logger_0.2.2          BiocStyle_2.26.0     
#>  [4] seqinr_4.2-23         knitr_1.42            rmarkdown_2.20       
#>  [7] openxlsx_4.2.5.2      shinyWidgets_0.7.6    ggdendro_0.1.23      
#> [10] shinycssloaders_1.0.0 excelR_0.4.0          zeallot_0.1.0        
#> [13] DT_0.27               plotly_4.10.1         ggplot2_3.4.1        
#> [16] data.table_1.14.8     shinyjs_2.1.0         shinydashboard_0.7.2 
#> [19] shiny_1.7.4           gridExtra_2.3         sangerseqR_1.34.0    
#> [22] phangorn_2.11.1       reshape2_1.4.4        DECIPHER_2.26.0      
#> [25] RSQLite_2.3.0         Biostrings_2.66.0     GenomeInfoDb_1.34.9  
#> [28] XVector_0.38.0        IRanges_2.32.0        S4Vectors_0.36.2     
#> [31] BiocGenerics_0.44.0   ape_5.7               stringr_1.5.0        
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] nlme_3.1-162           bitops_1.0-7           fs_1.6.1              
#>  [4] bit64_4.0.5            httr_1.4.5             R.cache_0.16.0        
#>  [7] bslib_0.4.2            utf8_1.2.3             R6_2.5.1              
#> [10] DBI_1.1.3              lazyeval_0.2.2         colorspace_2.1-0      
#> [13] ade4_1.7-22            withr_2.5.0            tidyselect_1.2.0      
#> [16] bit_4.0.5              compiler_4.2.2         cli_3.6.0             
#> [19] sass_0.4.5             scales_1.2.1           quadprog_1.5-8        
#> [22] digest_0.6.31          R.utils_2.12.2         pkgconfig_2.0.3       
#> [25] htmltools_0.5.4        styler_1.9.0           fastmap_1.1.1         
#> [28] htmlwidgets_1.6.1      rlang_1.0.6            rstudioapi_0.14       
#> [31] jquerylib_0.1.4        generics_0.1.3         jsonlite_1.8.4        
#> [34] zip_2.2.2              dplyr_1.1.0            R.oo_1.25.0           
#> [37] RCurl_1.98-1.10        magrittr_2.0.3         GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.9
#> [40] Matrix_1.5-3           Rcpp_1.0.10            munsell_0.5.0         
#> [43] fansi_1.0.4            lifecycle_1.0.3        R.methodsS3_1.8.2     
#> [46] stringi_1.7.12         yaml_2.3.7             MASS_7.3-58.2         
#> [49] zlibbioc_1.44.0        plyr_1.8.8             grid_4.2.2            
#> [52] blob_1.2.3             promises_1.2.0.1       crayon_1.5.2          
#> [55] lattice_0.20-45        pillar_1.8.1           igraph_1.4.1          
#> [58] codetools_0.2-19       fastmatch_1.1-3        reprex_2.0.2          
#> [61] glue_1.6.2             evaluate_0.20          BiocManager_1.30.20   
#> [64] vctrs_0.5.2            httpuv_1.6.9           gtable_0.3.1          
#> [67] purrr_1.0.1            tidyr_1.3.0            cachem_1.0.7          
#> [70] xfun_0.37              mime_0.12              xtable_1.8-4          
#> [73] later_1.3.0            viridisLite_0.4.1      tibble_3.1.8          
#> [76] memoise_2.0.1          ellipsis_0.3.2
```

Comment: I used your code and ran the launchapp() function on the contigs. Below is the error code. Listening onhttp://127.0.0.1:6825
Warning: Error in value[[3L]]: Couldn't normalize path in `addResourcePath`, with arguments: `prefix` = 'AdminLTE-2.0.6'; `directoryPath` = 'F:/biocbuild/bbs-3.16-bioc/R/library/shinydashboard/AdminLTE'
  3: runApp
  2: print.shiny.appobj
  1: <Anonymous>

Comment: Hi, Thank you for responding back. I am using Windows 10 R version 4.2.2. I edited my question to include the sessioninfo() for the package. I also recently commented the error I encountered from using your code. It's probably because my version of R is not updated because its Windows.

Comment: Another comment: I tried updating the Bioconductor package but I am using the newest version of it. However, when I used 'BiocManager::install(version='devel')', I ran across this error: Error: Bioconductor version '3.17' requires R version '4.3'; use
`BiocManager::install(version = '3.16')` with R version 4.2; see
https://bioconductor.org/install'. Is it because I am using Windows? If so, how could I use the example code in another program?

Comment: Another comment: I knitted your code again and this was the error I encountered: 
`Error in parse_block(g[-1], g[1], params.src, markdown_mode) : 
Duplicate chunk label 'unnamed-chunk-1', which has been used for the chunk:
library(reprex)
library(sangeranalyseR)
data("sangerAlignmentData")
data("sangerContigData")
data("sangerReadFData")
Calls: <Anonymous> ... process_file -> split_file -> lapply -> FUN -> parse_block                                                                           
Execution halted'

Comment: Looks like you my have a few issues to deal with. One potential issue is your shiny package install. First thing I'd do is, in a new session, reinstall shiny (`install.packages("shiny")`) and run the example code from https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-basic.html, then any issues with shiny and related packages should be able to be identified and solved.